# C++ How can I hide a public class?

Tags: c++

I'm coding a game engine and I'm creating some resource base classes such as vertexes, textures, fonts, etc.

Now I'm creating some basic classes that I want to be exposed to another programmer that uses these base classes, such as Image (uses textures), Text (uses fonts), Models (uses vertexes) etc

The game engine is also exposed, so they can call it's functions and such for coding a game.

But I don't want them to access the base classes at all, and I don't want it to conflict with their classes as well.
For example, they might want to create a class named "Material" for something ingame but my resources already have a "Material" class, how can I avoid the conflict and even better, hide these base classes (so they don't mess with it and break something)?

**Edit:** For example, I have the exposed class **Image**.
It contains private instances of a *Quad* and *Texture* base classes, and my resource manager makes sure there's always only one of these loaded (so I don't have duplicate textures/quads in memory).

*Texture* itself has a width/height, and manages the data loaded to the card. Same for *Quad*.

**Image** makes sure that when an image resize is requested, it changes everything that needs to be changed and reuploads the data to the card.

*Texture* and *Quad* are public because they're used nearly everywhere, there's the modules and some classes that apply effects to it.

They (other programmers) can use **Image** as instances, for inheritance, or as members, since it manages itself, and I want only this **Image** class exposed, so they don't ever know there's a *Quad* and *Texture* classes and that it also doesn't interfere with their class naming as well.

Comment: You may hide constructors or destructors by making them public or private. That will at least prevent (illegal) instantiations.

Comment: make stuff private and use public getters and setters?

Comment: [Namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent? That someone accidentally uses the Material class when they should use a class derived from it? Or do you have a Material class that "doesn't exist" outside your engine, and just don't want the user's class to collide with `Material`?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent access to base classes that my engine uses to manage it, if they access it they might change their ID (will totally mess with the ID setup/lookup from my resource module), or change some data or parameters that aren't supposed to be changed directly. The base classes I'm making do all the functions required and then changes the parameters, and that's the only classes I want exposed. The other base classes need to be public because they can be accessed from other modules as well.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but it sounds like `friend`s might come in handy here. With friends you can make things private to all but a few specific classes.

Comment: Please **show** what kind of access you are trying to prevent. Give an example of malicious/erroneous code you want to stop.

Comment: Namespace and don't export. That's the closest you can get to existing and being usable but hidden to end-users.

Comment: I read the title and thought "... under the mattress?" *ducks*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first (and easiest) method is to enclose all objects in your library in a specific namespace.

Then it gets a bit more complicated.  If you are exporting "public classes" that simply make use of "internal classes" via containment, you can do that using forward declarations, and keeping pointers to the "private classes" you use.  This can be done for behaviors and attributes using the [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)

Here's an example:

```
namespace Foo
{
   class BarImpl;

   class Bar
   {
   // ...
   private:
      std::unique_ptr<BarImpl> object_;
   };
}
```

However, if your "public classes" require the definition of your "private classes" (either through direct containment, or inheritance) there isn't really a good way to provide your library (*in source form*) to users without providing "easy" access to those supporting classes.